# How to automate installation process of any windows software application

Tags: automation, installation

I want to automate the installation process of any windows .exe/application software. 
For example: I have "npp.7.Installer.x64" .exe file and I want to install this .exe/application through any scripting or tool instead of manual process.

I had tried with "AutoIT" tool but I am unable to achieve the results. 
Please suggest me a appropriate way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does "python" script helps to make to automate the windows application with mouse and keyboard hover? Because some software we need to change installation path, select radio buttons and mark/unmark the multiple checkbox.

Comment: "I want to automate the installation process of any windows .exe/application software" is way, way too broad of a problem to be covered on any Q&A site.  As for your specific task with `npp.7.Installer.x64.exe`, show what you tried with AutoIT, what the results were, and why they weren't acceptable to you.

Comment: I had tried script line of code in "SciTE" script AutoIT tool:- 
`Run("D:\npp.7.Installer.x64")
Sleep(1000)`
But it will not showing installation window

Comment: Above script code of lines shows following output error:
`>"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\SciTE\..\autoit3.exe" /ErrorStdOut "D:\AutoIT\Notepad.au3"    
>Exit code: 0    Time: 1.103`

Comment: Why are you leaving the extension off of the executable's file name?  Try `Run("D:\npp.7.Installer.x64.exe")`.  I don't know about AutoIt, but exit code 0 usually indicates success, and seeing as how it takes over a second to run, is the installation being performed silently? Also, you should be editing this information into the question itself.

Comment: I had tried with including .exe prefix, some getting same result.But we run above code with already installed notepad application and run the script code i.e. `Run("C:\Windows\notepad.exe")
Sleep(1000)` 
it has open "Untitled-Notepad" successfully but not work with fresh install application.

Comment: If you double-click on `npp.7.Installer.x64.exe` does it show an installer, or it just runs silently?  You'll need to see what that specific `.exe` supports for customizing the install.  This is why the goal of automating _any_ Windows application installer is such a complex topic.

Comment: `Manual steps:` When I am double click on `npp.7.Installer.x64.exe`, it open `User Account Control` with following message `Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device` after click on `yes` it open `installer window` of notepad.

Comment: It's probably the UAC prompt that's tripping it up.  Your installation script will have to be run elevated (ideal) or elevate itself with the `RunAs()` function (not ideal).  For testing, if you elevate the SciTE/`autoit3.exe` process the script will probably display the installer as expected.

Comment: I had try with RunAS() function also but getting same result. And I am unable to understand your above point related to `elevated`

Comment: Hi I have get an answer and able to do with python script. Thanks @BACON for your kind approach.

Answer (score -1):

I have write code in python command line with administration permission and write below lines:

**app = Application().start(r"D:\npp.7.Installer.x64.exe")**

Above code successfully pop the Installation window of notepad.